# Which file gets executed before _Events.groovy in Grails?

Tags: grails

I have an import on `_Events.groovy` for a class that is not yet compiled. I want to compile the file before the script is executed. Any clarification on Grails startup execution sequence is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to "soft load" the class in `_Events.groovy` by doing something like this:

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.compiler.GrailsProjectCompiler


GrailsProjectCompiler projectCompiler = new GrailsProjectCompiler(pluginSettings)
projectCompiler.configureClasspath()

....
loadClass ('<your fully qualified class name>')
....

loadClass = { className ->
    def load = { name ->
        classLoader.loadClass (name)
    }

    try {
        load (className)
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ignored) {
        projectCompiler.compileAll()
        load (className)
    }
}
```

The above code (from [grails-cucumber](https://github.com/hauner/grails-cucumber/blob/master/scripts/_Events.groovy)) was originally based on [spock](https://github.com/spockframework/spock-grails/blob/master/spock-grails/plugin/scripts/_Events.groovy)'s code.

It has changed a little bit since then. The `GrailProjectCompiler` stuff was a tip from  [Graeme Rocher](https://stackoverflow.com/users/259167/graeme-rocher) [here](https://github.com/hauner/grails-cucumber/issues/31).